# Combining two columns of data frame in a new column containing all unique cases

Tags: r

Hi I have a data frame with several columns (more than 10) that I want to combine in a new column containing all the cases.

My data looks like:

```
COL1   COL2  COL3
A      A     C
B      C     D
C      E     K
```

I want to make a new column that contains all unique elements of the tree columns as follows:

```
COL4   
A      
B     
C
D
E
K
```

After trying different codes I did not managed to do it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: We can try `data.frame(col1 = sort(unique(unlist(df1))))`

Comment: Adding a new column may not work because dataframes require all columns to have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unlist`, get the `unique` elements and `sort` to create a new `data.frame`

```
data.frame(COL4 = sort(unique(unlist(df1))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   COL4
#1    A
#2    B
#3    C
#4    D
#5    E
#6    K
```

Answer (score 1):

By `unique.default` and `sort`

```
data.frame(COL4 = sort(unique.default(sapply(df1, unique))), stringsAsFactors = F)

#  COL4
#1    A
#2    B
#3    C
#4    D
#5    E
#6    K
```